# How to include dialogs in Phonegap v3.4.0

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I have downloaded dialogs with this command:

```
phonegap plugin add org.apache.cordova.dialogs
```

I have the folders, I have included this into my xml:

```
<feature name="Notification"><param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" /></feature> //For local
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" /> //for live builds
```

However only the building on build.phonegap.com will get the dialogs working.

How on earth do I include them for my local builds.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Not with plugins that access device features when testing with a browser. You may be able to test them locally with emulators but it's not a big deal to push to Git and build a new version to test it, is it? The notifications aren't very complex.